# glossary-extra's autoindex and polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, incompatibility, glossaries-extra

The following example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

gives me this error message:

```
Runaway argument?
html\@empty "\@nnil "\@empty \@glsxtr@endescspch \let \@glo@sort \@gls@checkedm
kidx \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@glsxtr@autoindex@escquote.
```

If I comment out either the three lines for the `polyglossia` setup or the line adding the dual index for the abbreviations it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-quote character `"` is makeindex's default escape character. The `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` package tries to search the sort and actual values for instances of this character to escape it, otherwise it will be misinterpreted by makeindex. Ulrike's answer has already explained that `"` is made active with the `german` language setting, which breaks this mechanism.

In this case, the simplest solution is to choose a different character (which should be one that isn't active). The base `glossaries` package provides `\GlsSetQuote` for the makeindex escape character used with the `glossaries` interface. The `glossaries-extra` package provides `\GlsXtrSetEscChar` for the `dualindex` setting. It's best to set them both to the same character:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\GlsSetQuote{+}
\GlsXtrSetEscChar{+}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

If you use the `makeglossaries` script (or `makeglossaries-lite`), this will automatically invoke `makeindex` with the `-g` switch, which deals with the glossary files.

The normal index needs to have a custom style that sets the quote character:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\begin{filecontents*}{dualindex.ist}
quote '+'
\end{filecontents*}

\GlsSetQuote{+}
\GlsXtrSetEscChar{+}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

If the file is called `test.tex`, then the document build is:

```
xelatex test
makeglossaries test
makeindex -s dualindex.ist test
xelatex test
```

If you're using `xindy` instead of `makeindex` for the normal index, the indexing is still performed using `\index` with `@` indicating the actual value, `|` indicating the encap (format) and `!` indicating the level. This means that `\GlsXtrSetEscChar` is still needed to change the character used to escape these characters if their literal use is needed from the default `"` to a non active character:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrSetEscChar{+}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

According to the `texindy` manual (`man texindy`), the makeindex emulation isn't completely compatible:

> The MakeIndex compatibility definitions support only the default raw
>   index syntax and markup definition. It is not possible to configure
>   raw index parsing or use a MakeIndex style file to describe output
>   markup.

So it might not be possible to instruct `texindy` that the escape character has changed, but if none of those special characters occur literally in the contents of `\index`, then it hopefully shouldn't matter.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using xindy (taken care of by latexmk) to build the index.

Comment: Actually this solution seems to work out of the box with latexmk and xindy, or rather texindy, apparently the `dualindex.ist` file is not necessary even. But, on my real file, it still doesn't work, I get the same error message as mentioned [in my comment to Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435494/glossary-extras-autoindex-and-polyglossia/435533#comment1092137_435512), apparently yet another problem I will need to isolate.

Comment: @muk.li Once you can get a MWE that demonstrates it, you can ask a new follow-up question with a link back to this one.

Comment: I will. I'm afraid it might get more than one follow-up question, in another version of my original file I now get strange things happening with footnotes, and an index entry added by glossaries-extra which was supposed to be sorted under Y appearing under P.

Comment: @muk.li That's okay as long as it's one question per problem with a MWE illustrating the particular error. Regarding inappropriate sorting, check the indexing file to make sure that the sort value is correct.

Comment: I managed to isolate one of the problems, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436421/59023).

Answer (score 1):

Polyglossia (or more precisely gloss-german) makes the `"` active directly. And this then breaks following packages which uses `"`. Move the `\setotherlanguage{german}` to `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}

\setotherlanguage{german}
\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Or use babel which doesn't have this problem and works fine with xelatex and lualatex too:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}


\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shifting the language definitions to after the loading of glossaries-extra solves it for my example above, but in my real file unfortunately not, the first call to gls produces `ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@ 
                                  ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
l.94 \gls{yh}` I'll try to change my example to reproduce this behaviour.