# glossaries-extra autoindex and sorting of entries with language switching command

Tags: polyglossia, glossaries-extra

Follow up question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435494/59023).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]

\newcommand{\skti}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsSetQuote{+}
\GlsXtrSetEscChar{+}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossname}{firstuc}
\GlsXtrEnableIndexFormatOverride
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexentry}[1]{\string\glsentryfirst{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
%  \ifglshaslong{#2}%
%  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{long}}%
%  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
%}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\newabbreviation{yh}{YH}{\skti{Yoginīhṛdaya}}
%\newabbreviation{yh}{YH}{Yoginīhṛdaya}

\begin{document}

\gls{yh}


\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This example compiles fine. If I comment in the redefined `\glsxtrautoindexassignsort` it stops working,

```
Writing index file test.idx 
(./test.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@ 
                                  ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
l.34 \gls{yh}

?
```

unless I remove my language switching command, by changing to the commented out version.

The redefinition of `\glsxtrautoindexassignsort` has been copied from `sample-autoindex.tex`, it should have the effect of the entry being sorted according to its long form (Yoginīhṛdaya), not the short one (YH), which is something one would want. I compile this with latexmk calling xelatex and xindy (texindy).

EDIT: changing the definition of `\skti` to use `\newrobustcmd` it compiles, but the "Yoginīhṛdaya" entry gets sorted under S, presumably because of the presence of `\skti`. `\indexentry{\\skti {Yoginīhṛdaya}@\glsentryfirst{yh}}{1}` is the line in the idx file. Curiously in my real file it appears under Y, but before other entries, suggesting that it has been sorted under YH. The idx file line there is `\indexentry{\skti {Yoginīhṛdaya}@\glsentryfirst{yh}}{1}`, for some reason the testing file has two backslashes, `\\skti`.

Comment: Try defining `\skti` as a robust command. (That is, replace `\newcommand` with `\newrobustcmd`.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glossaries` package's `xindy` option uses xindy's native format (rather than the makeindex emulation provided with texindy). This means that it has to escape xindy's special characters rather than makeindex's. For example, if you have:

```
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={\skti{Yoginīhṛdaya}},description={}}
```

with the `xindy` option, the `sort` value (obtained from the `name`) has to have the backslash escaped so that it's written to the xindy file as:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("\\skti {Yoginīhṛdaya}" "\\glossentry{sample}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
```

The autoindexing function uses makeindex syntax in `\index` and also tries to escape any special characters. It should just escape the special characters identified by commands like `\GlsXtrSetEscChar` but it seems it's also still trying to escape the backslash because the base `glossaries` code is in native `xindy` mode. That's why you get the double backslash `\\skti` in the indexing file.

One way around this is to provide a definition of `\glsxtrautoindexassignsort` that strips `\skti` out when obtaining the sort value from the `long` field:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield*{long}{#2}%
  {%
    \let\orgskti\skti
    \let\skti\@firstofone
    \protected@edef#1{\glscurrentfieldvalue}%
    \let\skti\orgskti
  }%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}
\makeatother
```

This temporarily defines `\skti` to `\@firstofone`, which means that the command will be removed during the `\protected@edef`.

Another possibility is to move the formatting command out of the `long` field and into the abbreviation style:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#2}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{long}}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\renewcommand{\glslongfont}[1]{\skti{#1}}
\newabbreviation{yh}{YH}{Yoginīhṛdaya}
```