# glossaries-extra autoindex, manual sorting of entry

Tags: sorting, glossaries-extra

(Kind of a follow up question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436421/59023).) The following example contains a definition of an abbreviation which requires some extra care: [Śatika-]Kālajñāna is supposed to be sorted, both in the list of abbreviations and the index, under Kālajñāna. (btw. I do have a xindy file taking care of all the diacritics, but of course that does not help here.) Probably creating an extra xindy file for exceptions like this could be a way of dealing with the problem, but I hope there's a cleaner way of doing it?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]

\newrobustcmd{\skti}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}}

\usepackage[abbreviations,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsSetQuote{+}
\GlsXtrSetEscChar{+}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossname}{firstuc}
\GlsXtrEnableIndexFormatOverride
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexentry}[1]{\string\glsentryfirst{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#2}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{long}}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\newabbreviation{yh}{YH}{\skti{Yoginīhṛdaya}}
\newabbreviation{śkj}{{}[Ś]KJ}{\skti{[Śatika-]Kālajñāna}}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield*{long}{#2}%
  {%
    \let\orgskti\skti
    \let\skti\@firstofone
    \protected@edef#1{\glscurrentfieldvalue}%
    \let\skti\orgskti
  }%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\gls{yh}
\gls{śkj}

\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the simplest method is to just use the `sort` key:

```
\newabbreviation[sort={Kālajñāna}]{śkj}{{}[Ś]KJ}{\skti{[Śatika-]Kālajñāna}}
```

This deals with the glossary list. The sort value for the index is obtained in your document through the `long` field (Within `\glsxtrautoindexassignsort`) so one way of dealing with that is to provide a command that formats the square bracket material:

```
\newrobustcmd{\squarebracket}[1]{[#1]}
```

(I recommend choosing a better name for the command.) Then the abbreviation can be defined as:

```
\newabbreviation[sort={Kālajñāna}]{śkj}{{}[Ś]KJ}{\skti{\squarebracket{Śatika-}Kālajñāna}}
```

This custom command can locally be redefined to ignore its argument when obtaining the sort value:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield*{long}{#2}%
  {%
    \let\orgskti\skti
    \let\orgsquarebracket\squarebracket
    \let\skti\@firstofone
    \let\squarebracket\@gobble
    \protected@edef#1{\glscurrentfieldvalue}%
    \let\skti\orgskti
    \let\squarebracket\orgsquarebracket
  }%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]

\newrobustcmd{\skti}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}}

\usepackage[abbreviations,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsSetQuote{+}
\GlsXtrSetEscChar{+}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\newrobustcmd{\squarebracket}[1]{[#1]}

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossname}{firstuc}
\GlsXtrEnableIndexFormatOverride
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexentry}[1]{\string\glsentryfirst{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#2}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{long}}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\newabbreviation{yh}{YH}{\skti{Yoginīhṛdaya}}
\newabbreviation[sort={Kālajñāna}]{śkj}{{}[Ś]KJ}{\skti{\squarebracket{Śatika-}Kālajñāna}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield*{long}{#2}%
  {%
    \let\orgskti\skti
    \let\orgsquarebracket\squarebracket
    \let\skti\@firstofone
    \let\squarebracket\@gobble
    \protected@edef#1{\glscurrentfieldvalue}%
    \let\skti\orgskti
    \let\squarebracket\orgsquarebracket
  }%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\gls{yh}
\gls{śkj}

\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The abbreviation glossary file (`.glo-abr`) contains:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("YH" "\\glossentry{yh}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("Kālajñāna" "\\glossentry{śkj}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
```

The first argument of the `:tkey` part is the sort value. The index file contains:

```
\indexentry{Yoginīhṛdaya@\glsentryfirst{yh}}{1}
\indexentry{Kālajñāna@\glsentryfirst{śkj}}{1}
```

The part before the `@` is the sort value. So in both cases, the bracketed part has been stripped.

(As an aside, I would use [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) rather than `xindy` for this type of document, for both the glossary and index, as then commands like `\squarebracket` can locally be redefined just for `bib2gls`'s use, but I realise that switching in an existing document isn't simple.)